# android status bar icon run code block

Tags: android, android-activity, statusbar

i know how to open an activity from a statusbar item, but is their a way to run a small block of code without opening a new activity? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `getBroadcast()` or `getService()` `PendingIntent` instead of a `getActivity()` `PendingIntent`.